# Does wait() disrupt the main process?

Tags: c, fork, child-process

The following is the main part of my code ( adopted from "advanced linux programming", Listing 3.7 ):

```
void clean_up_child_process ( int signal_number ) {
  /* Clean up the child process. */
  int status ;
  wait ( &status ) ;

  printf ( " wait finished \n" ) ;

  /* Store its exit status in a global variable. */
  child_exit_status = status ;
}

int main() {
  /* Handle SIGCHLD by calling clean_up_child_process. */
  pid_t child_pid ;
  struct sigaction sigchld_action ;
  memset ( &sigchld_action, 0, sizeof(sigchld_action) ) ;
  sigchld_action.sa_handler = &clean_up_child_process ;

  sigaction ( SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL ) ;

  /* Now do things, including forking a child process */
  child_pid = fork () ;

  if ( child_pid > 0 ) {
    sleep ( 60 ) ; // it ends after only 15 seconds
  } else {
    sleep ( 15 ) ;
  exit (0) ;
  }

  printf ( "%d\n", child_exit_status ) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

My conjecture is that the program takes about 60 seconds to finish. However what is actually happening is: once started, it runs for only about 15 seconds immediately after the the termination of the child process. I wonder why `sleep ( 60 )` does not cause the main process to last for a while, or it is disrupted by `wait()` function.

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `sleep()` so you have no reason idea if the sleep succeeded or not, and in the latter case, why. Quoting from the Linux manpage, `sleep` returns  "zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read [a `sleep` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) you will see that the function

> sleep either until the number of
>          real-time seconds specified in seconds have elapsed or **until a signal
>          arrives which is not ignored**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Since you don't ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal, the `sleep` function will be interrupted when the child exits and the parent process get the signal.